# Error trying to get Guard to work with Spork and Cucumber on Rails using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, guard, spork

I am trying to get Guard to work with Spork and Cucumber. I am creating a Rails app with rspec.I have tried many different things to no avail and am feeling defeated.

I am assuming the problem has to be either in the Gemfile or Guardfile. I am a novice just learning so if you see something in my setup that I can improve and/or do without, feel free to let me know, I'd love some feedback.

One thing though, as far as I can tell, Cucumber seems to be working. However, every time I try to run Guard, it says :

```
ERROR - Could not load 'guard/spork-rails' or find class Guard::Sporkrails
ERROR - cannot load such file -- guard/spork-rails
ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is: > [#] undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
ERROR - Could not start Spork server for RSpec, Cucumber. Make sure you can use it manually first.
```

Here is my  Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'guard-gitpusher'
gem 'bundler'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'guard-rake'
  gem 'guard-gitpusher'
  gem 'guard-yaml'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
  gem 'gherkin'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.4.2'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6' 
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails' 
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'guard-migrate'
  gem 'guard-rake'
  gem 'guard-migrate'
  gem 'guard-webrick'
  gem 'guard-gitpusher'
  gem 'guard-yaml'
  gem 'cucumber',  '1.2.5'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false 
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

and here is my Guardfile :

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end

guard 'cucumber' do
watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
watch(%r{^features/support/.+$}) { 'features' }
watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end

guard 'spork-rails' do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.*\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.*\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end


guard 'bundler' do
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch(%r{^.+\.gemspec$})
end

guard 'webrick' do
end

guard :yaml do
  watch(%r{^config/(.*).yml})
end

guard 'rspec', after_all_pass: false, cli: '--color --format nested --drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)\.rb}) { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/decorators/(.+)_decorator\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_controller_spec.rb" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb') { "spec/requests" }

  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/(.+)\.rabl$}) { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_controller_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^spec/requests/support/views/(.+)_view\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_controller_spec.rb" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

and lastly, here is my spec_helper.rb :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false


  config.order = "random"
end

end

Spork.each_run do

end
```

Any feedback and/or insight would be extremely helpful and appreciated too!

Answer (score 1):

The gem `spork-rails` is the Spork server and not a Guard plugin, but `guard-spork` is a Guard plugin to manage Spork servers. So you need to change

`` `
guard 'spork-rails' do ``

to

`guard 'spork' do`

to automatically start the Spork server when Guard starts.